# Where should I write the code in Intelij IDEA after installing HtmlUnit and Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, web-scraping, intellij-idea, htmlunit

I first downloaded HtmlUnit and Gradle, then I did integration with IntelliJ, and when I want to write the import code to using HtmlUnit, I don't know where to place this code in IntelliJ,
And I have used IntelliJ many times, just have other folders now

I have attached [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep1OF.png) of my IntelliJ if it could help,
Thank you!

I tried to write code in all kinds of folders but it would have looked wrong, I hope I can know where to write the code after installing the plugins in Intelligence

Answer (score 0):

Java has certain ideas on where source code needs to go; it's a mapping from packages to folders. A class `Foo` needs to be in `Foo.java`. If that class lives in the `com.example.java` package, that needs to be in a folder `com/example/java`. This should be covered in any textbook or [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html). IntelliJ just follows these standards.

Gradle also has its opinions on [how a project should be organized](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html). You can run e.g., `gradle init --type java-application` to have Gradle create a standard folder structure for you. (The `gradle` folder is for Gradle itself.)

You will end up with a `src/main/java/` folder for your source code and a `src/test/java/` folder for your unit tests.